# Does the null hypothesis always conform to a normal distribution?

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation, confidence-interval

Hopefully this is an appropriate place for this question.

Let's imagine I have a function Trader(param), which takes a matrix of market data as a parameter, and then chooses whether to buy or sell.  I feed it a bunch of historical data, and it spits out series of numbers representing the value of each trade, sometimes making money, sometimes losing.  These numbers belong to a dataset called Sample.

I have a hypothesis: giving real money to Trader() has a positive expected value.  I want to find out if my dataset Sample is large enough to confirm this hypothesis according to some confidence interval Z, within a margin of error M.  My required sample size is N.  I'm led to believe that this is the appropriate formula:

N >= ((Z * σ) ÷ M)^2

Let's plug in an actual value for Z.  I want to be 95% confident.  95% of the data points within a normal distribution are within 1.96 standard deviations of the mean, therefore Z == 1.96, for 95% confidence.

But does my null hypothesis necessarily conform to a normal distribution?  If I calculated the value of every possible trade within my historical market data - that's to say buy on every day, and sell on every day in the future of the buying day, giving me a very large amount of potential trades - would *that* be my null hypothesis?  And if so, would I then want to compute how many standard deviations from the mean 95% of these data points fall?

Comment: Consider using LaTeX. Instead of N >= ((Z * σ) ÷ M)^2, you can type N \ge \left( \frac{Z\sigma}{M}\right)^2 between dollar signs to give 
$$N \ge \left( \frac{Z\sigma}{M}\right)^2$$

Comment: Without knowing the nature of the data, no one can say for sure that a confidence interval should be based on a normal distribution.

Comment: @BruceET What kind of information about the data would affect that decision?